# why does a closed circuit represent a false proposition? (Claude Shannon thesis)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

In reading through Claude Shannon's paper: A Symbolic Analysis of Relay and Switching Circuits.

As a software engineer, I got confused by Shannon's choice to have 0 as representing a closed circuit, i.e with electricity flowing through, and following from that, 0 as representing a false proposition.

Intuitively, it seems like:
- 1 should represent a closed circuit (but I can deal with this not being the case)
- A closed circuit should represent a proposition that is true

Why would a closed circuit, i.e a circuit with electricity flowing through it be considered to represent a proposition that is false? Why would an open circuit represent a proposition that is true when there is no electricity flowing through it? Am I holding on too firmly to notions of logical operators from programming languages?

Comment: It is only a convention... Maybe the reason for adopting *closed* to mean$ 0$ is suggested at page 4 : "or closed (zero impedence)".

Comment: The choice of $0$ for False was due to [Boole](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boole/#MathAnalLogi1847).